# How can I obtain the number of likes for YouTube videos based on content input by the user, without using an API?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program that retrieves links, such as those for all videos related to content chosen by the user

Currently, the code I've written doesn't return anything but empty sets. What am I doing wrong?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import tkinter
from tkinter import simpledialog

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()


content = simpledialog.askstring("Input", "Veuillez saisir une chaîne de caractères :", parent=root)

url = f"https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={content}"

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

set_likes = set()
set_links = set()

#getting number of views
for video in soup.find_all("a", href=True):
    video_href = video['href']
    #Verify if the url is correct
    if "/watch?" in video_href:
        video_url = f"https://www.youtube.com{video_href}"
        video_response = requests.get(video_url)
        video_soup = BeautifulSoup(video_response.content, 'html.parser')
        
        #Getting number of likes
        try:
            likes = video_soup.find("button", class_="like-button-renderer-like-button").text
            set_likes.add(likes)
            set_links.add(video_url)
        except AttributeError:
            print(f"Impossible to get links for the videos: {video_url}")

# Afficher les résultats
print("links:", set_links)
print("likes:", set_likes)
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Using `requests` is fine when you scrape pure HTML websites or things like JSON API. However, YouTube and other modern apps work differently than the static websites - they run scripts that download and render the website after the basic HTML file is downloaded. This makes it impossible to scrape with pure requests - you will only get the basic HTML code, including references to some JS, which would not include anything specific.

To see what it looks like, try:

```py
r = requests.get('https://any_website')
r.text
```

And check out the results. In many cases it would not include any serious content.

In order to scrape websites rendered in this particular way, you have to emulate a browser, so that the website behaves as if a regular user was rendering it in Chrome or Firefox. For that you can try:

- [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)
- [Scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html) (the documentation here is quite helpful to get to understand the problem better.

Comment: Hi jarekko, welcome to SO. This is a great start for a first answer. However, while your links may solve the OP's question, answers that rely heavily on links are discouraged for [these reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/236527). Please consider updating your answer so that it is self-contained and includes the minimum amount of code to solve the OP's question. Thanks

Comment: @LTyrone thank you for the tip. this question requires quite an elaborate answer. I will try to provide it with an update, is that OK?

Comment: Yes, do what you are able. Some questions by their nature require a lot of code/explanation.